# Run a PHP script from another PHP script by exec(): It executes multiple times

Tags: php, linux

I´m trying to execute a php script (called B.php) using exec() command from another php script (called A.php):

A.php:

```
<?
$result = exec('php5 B.php');
echo $result;
?>
```

B.php:

```
<?
sleep(10);
echo"finished";
?>
```

When i run A.php from my browser, i see that B.php is executed several times, not only once.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're routing all requests through PHP, is your browser trying to fetch `favicon.ico` and getting PHP instead of a 404?

Comment: I´m afraid that is not the problem. If I run A.php from the command line it happens the same